# Matlab urlread error within timer function

Tags: php, mysql, matlab, timer

I am using a timer function in matlab to continuously execute a certain script. Within this script, I am using `urlread` to retrieve data from webservices, which works like a charm.

I am now trying to use `urlread` to execute a simple http-request within this script to insert data into a mysql-database. Thus, I simply specify the url-string and define the value to be parsed to the php parser.

Code-within script being executed in timer-function:

```
db_url = 'http://someurl/update.php?value=';
db_url = strcat(db_url,num2str(value));
urlread(db_url);
clear db_url
```

My problem is the following: When I run the timer, it works fine for one execution, but then stops displaying the following error:

"Either this URL could not be parsed or the protocol is not supported."

What is going wrong? When I check my mysql database, I see that one new line has been added to my database, which means it generally works, just won't execute multiple times within the timer.

Any idea what is going wrong? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Where exactly, i.e. in which function was the exception thrown?

Comment: I can't exactly tell, since when the error occurs in the script being executed in the timer, no specific line is displayed. From my tests, I am pretty sure however, that it is the `urlread(db_url)` function. And again, it works fine for the first execution and only throws the error when the timer executes the script for the second time.

Comment: Hi, I figured out what the problem was (see answer below), thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. The `value` variable is an array with increasing in size each iteration. Thus, what I needed to do was specify `value(end)`, like so:

```
db_url = 'http://someurl/update.php?value=';
db_url = strcat(db_url,num2str(value(end)));
urlread(db_url);
clear db_url
```